# Какое ограничение на имя block devices в Linux?

Tags: linux, c

Ничего толком нагуглить не получилось, есть устройства в /proc/partitions. Вот колонка name, откуда это имя берется, можно ли его изменить?(С помощью makedev вроде можно)Какое ограничение по количеству букв в имени устройства?
Имена файлов в Linux ограничены 256 байтами, а вот имена устройств?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Блочное устройство - это файл, так что к нему применяются те же ограничения. 

Ваш вопрос похож на классику - проблему X-Y https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-xy/710#710

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @gbg Ну а имена блочных устройст откуда берутся? Их юзер задает или как?

Comment: Имена устройств задает система загрузки ОС, например, systemd.
Более того, она же создает еще пачку симлинков для того, чтобы к устройстам можно было обращаться по различным идентификатором. Вам бы лучше написать, что вы делаете, для того чтобы мы не гадали.

Comment: @gbg https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/libblkid/src/devname.c#L377
Это linux util, пытаюсь понять чем руководствуется разработчик, когда задал размер статического размера в 110. В этих же утилитах, только уже считывая из /proc/partition разработчик выставляет размер массиву 128 и так же с помощью sscanf считывает имена разделов, не боясь переполнения буфера. Интересно откуда такая смелость

Comment: @gdb вот пример кода со считыванием из /proc/partitions. https://gitlab.it-kraut.net/muhviehstah/android_bootable_recovery/-/blob/32aef7a2cf8ef3881e1efdce6cf693bc762cc604/libblkid/src/devname.c#L458
Почему 128 мне неясно и в чем такая уверенность тоже
В этом я и пытаюсь разобраться, насколько это надежно

Comment: Так напишите разработчику и спросите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя устройству назначает драйвер. Не скажу за `loop`, но `sda`, `sdb` и прочие `sd...` назначает SCSI драйвер.

Чтобы поменять схему именования, нужно изменить в файле [`drivers/scsi/sd.c`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/scsi/sd.c) функции

- [`sd_probe`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/13311e74253fe64329390df80bed3f07314ddd61/drivers/scsi/sd.c#L3407): ответственна за префикс `sd` в именах дисков,
- [`sd_format_disk_name`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/13311e74253fe64329390df80bed3f07314ddd61/drivers/scsi/sd.c#L3325): ответственна за использование букв `a-z` в именах дисков.

Максимальная длина имени диска - та часть, которая после `/dev/` - 32 байта. Чтобы изменить этот предел, нужно поменять значение константы [`DISK_NAME_LEN`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/13311e74253fe64329390df80bed3f07314ddd61/include/linux/genhd.h#L27) в `include/linux/genhd.h` и пересобрать ядро.

Comment: Спасибо большое, а в эти 32 байта включены номера разделов? sda1 sda256
Или 32 байта это только имя самого диска без номеров раздела

Comment: @АндрейПетров `DISK_NAME_LEN` только для `sda`, `sdb` и так далее. Номера в имена разделов добавляет драйвер файловой системы. Для имён разделов другое ограничение - имя раздела должно умещаться в поле [`s_id`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/13311e74253fe64329390df80bed3f07314ddd61/include/linux/fs.h#L1480) структуры `super_block`, но численно это те же самые 32 байта.